# SQLite - if not exists, insert column, else update OR set default value?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've got a table but I'm having so much trouble just setting the default value.
I create the table like this: 
 `CREATE TABLE test (id INT DEFAULT 0)` 
but this doesn't set the default value. How should I go around setting the default value?

Comment: How are you going to do INSERTs without specifying a value for the single `id` field?

Comment: That should work just fine.  See this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c3cb6/1/0) example.

Answer (score 0):

What you're using is the correct syntax for setting a default value:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect("")
>>> db.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id INT DEFAULT 0)")
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO test DEFAULT VALUES")
>>> for row in db.execute("SELECT * FROM test"):
...   print row
...
(0,)
```